# Feature Serving for h2o

Tags: h2o

I see h2o has model serving (as documented in "Productionizing H2O" at http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/productionizing.html#) but I don't see any reference to serving the feature pipeline.

Does h2o have a feature serving methodology? (for example, TensorFlow has feature serving via Apache Beam, which is served along with the model via TFServing.)